# iphone Alarm playing sound at a definite time

Tags: iphone

I am building an application in which I have to include an Alarm. In this scenario, I am not getting on which frame should I rely on. Adding, I need to play default audio file as recorded one. How can I play default audio files?? Please help me in this regard..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a local sound notification. You can go through [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Scheduling_iOS_4_iPhone_Local_Notifications) tutorial.

Also note that you can not use any sounds not provided within your application. Here is a extract from the docs:

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle or **UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName** to request the default system sound.